# "Please run using "bash"/"dash"/"sh"/"zsh", but not "." or "source"." when piping the miniconda install script to sh

Tags: shell, anaconda, miniconda

I'm trying to script the miniconda installation. The following:

```bash
curl --tlsv1.3 -LSf \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    | sh -s -- --help
```

gives(the `--help` is irrelevant, just a placeholder here):

```bash
Please run using "bash"/"dash"/"sh"/"zsh", but not "." or "source".
sh: line 16: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

Looking at the code, the relevant lines(14~17) are:

```bash
if ! echo "$0" | grep '\.sh$' > /dev/null; then
    printf 'Please run using "bash"/"dash"/"sh"/"zsh", but not "." or "source".\n' >&2
    return 1
fi
```

It checks if `${0}` ends with `.sh`. Without using temporary files, modifying the miniconda installer etc., is it possible to make this work?

Comment: I'm not super clear on what your question is, but if you want to run the installer and **you are** *"trying to script the miniconda installation"*, wouldn't removing the `-s -- --help` be enough? You might need `curl .... | sh -` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter The `--help` is just a placeholder; the problem is that the script simply looks at `$0` and exits if it doesn't end with `.sh`. `$0` is `sh` when `curl .... | sh -`-ing the script, which doesn't end with `.sh`. The only way I've found it to work is to save the file as `${something}.sh` and run it with `sh ${something}.sh`

Comment: 1) So (as I assumed before), you can't change the last block of code because it is embedded in the installer script you download with `curl` ? ... 2) Please remind me, what does `-s` do for `sh`? 3) You  would like your first block of code to work (minus `--help`) so you rely on the `pipe` mechanism to feed the script to `sh`, rather than saving a file and then launching `sh /tmp/InstallerScript.sh, correct? Will look at this later. Good luck!

Comment: I've looked at it now in detail and understand your dilemma . I don't see a solution short of submitting a change to the project that would allow for a `if ${skipShellTest}` or something like that. Did you try commenting out that block of code to be sure it would work as you expect if you got that resolved. I see binary data in there and have to wonder how that works (yes, compiled code), but how does it get stored into `/usr/bin/` or other protect area without `sudo` or other permission override. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for looking at their code and mentioning it here! I was confused about running miniconda installer interactively because I saved it as `miniconda_linux64` and thanks to your question I noticed that I can just rename the file to `miniconda_linux64.sh` to make it work. Regarding **your** question: Why do you not save to a file first, and then run that?

Comment: @lucidbrot there are a few, some of them are:

1) It's faster. If you pipe `curl` to `sh` like I did, `sh` will execute the script as it's "streamed" from `curl`, instead of waiting till it finishes downloading.

2) It's simpler. Generally, you download, execute, and delete the script. You could write a function to do that, or you could write a function to pipe it to sh, which is better. In this case, because the script uses a bad, hacky way to determine if it's being `source`d, you also have to `chmod +x` the script.

Comment: @lucidbrot 3) It uses less resources. Some of the things that happen when you save the file and execute it are:
the underlying filesystem will have to do filesystem things,
there will be a copy of that file in the disk buffer,
there will be a copy of that file in memory when it gets executed,
the file may get stored to disk if it gets flushed swapped out.

If you pipe it instead:
there will be a copy of that file in the pipe,
there will be a copy of that file in memory when it gets executed.

A lot less.